# How to calculate maximum of three in combined query

Tags: sql, ms-access

[usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDCDR.jpg)

The image shows works that I have done in access. The query "overall usage review" count the number of usages in each month by using combined query.

After this step, I want to show the maximum three of usage.quantity among 12months and calculate with the formula ( E.g., "Total MAX three months usage"/3)

E.g.,

```
Warehouse Part Number  ........................................................
   A          X01        9   16   7   14   10   5   9   11   6   3   11   5
   A          X02       20   22   10  12   20  17  18   29  14  13   11   19
   B          X01        8    7   3   26   17   6   3   2    5   10   8   14
   B          X05        9   10   16   6   10   4  13   12   6    4   3   6
```

I want to result it as below...

```
Warehouse Part Number   Maximum three usage quantity    Results
   A          X01                   41                   41/3
   A          X02                   71                   71/3
   B          X01                   57                    19
   B          X05                   39                    13
```

Someone told me to use dynamic sql, but I dont know what it is... Pls tell me how to solve this problem in detail. The problem stuck in my mind for a very long time...

Comment: You should fix your data structure so you have one data element per row, rather than having a bunch of different columns with the same value.

Comment: Sorry Bro. What do you mean? I dont get it..